# Transportable type requestfactory

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I'm developing an aplication with gwt and RequestFactory and I have a class that's something like this:

```
public MyClass{

private String someString;
private Object someObject;

public MyClass(){}

//Getters and Setters

}
```

Obviously if I make this an ValueProxy I'm unable to declare someObject as object because it isn't a RequestFactory transportable type. My question is: Can I declare it as an generic transportable type? How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use an `Object` ? 
If you need a "dynamic object" I would recommend to jsonify it and store the output as a `String` value.

On the client you can de-serialize it and use `JsonObject`, etc to access the properties.